# What is the difference between script tag, and "<%....%>" tag?

Tags: asp.net, html, web-applications, scripting

I have just started to work on web applications, and learning to use ASP.Net. I have come across two methods to add script in an HTML page. One is by using script tag, and other one is by using `<% ... %>` tag. But, I am unable to figure out, what is the difference between both, and which one should I prefer in which case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The script tag is used to specify full scripts (usually complete methods/function) (mostly client side scripts but you can also have server side script blocks) while the `<% ... %>` are used to include server side inline snippets.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I needed exactly this response, basically when to use which tag.

Answer (score 4):

The  tag can be JavaScript or the language in question. The <% %> is functionally equivalent to

```
<script language="C#|vb" runat="server">
```

In general, you put the code in code behind (win forms), so the only  is for client side script (generally JavaScript). With ASP.NET MVC, the <% %> is for marking up the view and is not really code.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to put code thingies around the `<script>` tags and it won't let me edit ;)

Answer (score 2):

`<% %>` is for asp.net coding and <script> tag can use for any language by specifying which language you want to use like this one `<script type="text/javascript">`  for javascript

Answer (score 2):

Script tags are used to add Javascript (or similar) script to the final HTML which is rendered by the browser, and hence allow client-side scripting.

`<% ... %>` tags are ASP tags that are processed on the server side, and will not be present in the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by `script` tag?

```
<script language="C#" runat="server">
...
</script>
```

this is used when you specify that you do not want to place the server code in a separated file, such as `myFile.aspx.cs` or in VB `myFile.aspx.vb`, this will be the code to run before the page is rendered and will act in compliance with the [ASP.NET Page Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) Cycle.

The tags `<% %>` are used to **place Server Code in your page**, just like plain old Classic ASP.

Normally we use as `Response.Write` using `<%= ... %>` but if you use Resources Files, you will end up using `<%$ ResourceFile.Variable %>` as well

It's a mean to **inject server code** into the page

Answer (score 1):

the script tag indicates where client script is going to be executed or if in a function where it is to be organized.  The <% .. %> is code that is executed on the webserver and is never seen by the client.

```
<script>
   window.alert("hi") // This will popup a hi message
</script>
<% responce.wrtie("hi") %>
```

When you load this page you would see a popup 
and the text hi however in the page source you would see

```
<script>
   window.alert("hi") // This will popup a hi message
</script>
hi
```

Comment: So, we will use "<%" tag for server-side scripting, and script tag for client side script, right! But, can it be changed. Like using script tag to write server side script? Edit: Checked other answers closely. Turns out I can use script tag for server side script too. So, the only differences is, "<%" tag can be used for inline script, and will not be visible in rendered html. Did I missed anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Particularly in case of ASP.net

Code inside script tag is directly placed directly under the class that is generated by the asp.net when the aspx page is requested.

(Every time a request is made to .aspx page , the page is parsed into a .cs file whose path  can be found out by using <%=GetType().Assembly.Location%>.And also you have to set the Debug=true in the page directive.)

Code inside <% %> is placed inside a method in the generated class file.
For example you can not write Response.Write() directly inside the script tag as it needs to be written inside a method.

Hope this helps.