# Invalid token 'try' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net, try-catch

Just started using ASPX files this morning and have hit a roadblock.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1519: Invalid token 'try' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Source Error:

Line 5:  int portno = 52791;
Line 6:  IPAddress ipa = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname).AddressList[0];
Line 7:  try
Line 8:  {
Line 9:      System.Net.Sockets.Socket sock = new System.Net.Sockets.Socket(System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork, System.Net.Sockets.SocketType.Stream, System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType.Tcp);

Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.aspx    Line: 7
```

from the following ASPX file code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import namespace="System" %>
<script runat="server">
string hostname = "localhost";
int portno = 52791;
IPAddress ipa = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname).AddressList[0];
try
{
    System.Net.Sockets.Socket sock = new System.Net.Sockets.Socket(System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork, System.Net.Sockets.SocketType.Stream, System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType.Tcp);
    sock.Connect(ipa, portno);
    if (sock.Connected == true)  // Port is in use and connection is successful
            string output = "Port is Closed";
    sock.Close();

}
catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ex)
{
    if (ex.ErrorCode == 10061)  // Port is unused and could not establish connection 
        string output = "Port is Open!";
    else
        string output = ex.Message;
}
</script>
<html>...
```

Hours of Googling have not helped my problem.

Comment: May be you forgot to wrap these things in a method?

Comment: The easy answer is don't do this in the markup; this is stuff that belongs in the code behind, in which your error would be obvious.

Comment: Also, you're defining the string `output` repeatedly in various scopes in which it will never be usable.  This is actually a compiler error, in addition to being nonsensical.

Comment: Based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5791777/298754), it looks like it's assuming that your script is Javascript rather than C#, and you need to explicitly inform it otherwise.

Comment: For inline code, use `<%` and `%>` instead of `<script runat="server">` and `</script>`.

Comment: Thanks everyone, helpful comments all around.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"  Debug="true" %>
<%@ Import namespace="System.Net" %>
<script runat="server">
public class Whatever
{
public static string output()
{
string hostname = "localhost";
int portno = 52791;
//IPAddress ipa = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname).AddressList[0];
byte[] ipb = {192,168,1,30};
IPAddress ipa = new IPAddress(ipb);
string ret = "";
try
{
    System.Net.Sockets.Socket sock = new System.Net.Sockets.Socket(System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork, System.Net.Sockets.SocketType.Stream, System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType.Tcp);
    sock.Connect(ipa, portno);
    if (sock.Connected == true)  // Port is in use and connection is successful
            ret = "Port is Closed";
    sock.Close();

}
catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ex)
{
    if (ex.ErrorCode == 10061)  // Port is unused and could not establish connection 
        ret = "Port is Open!";
    else
        ret = ex.Message;
}
return ret;
}
}
</script>
```